# How to assign multiple ActionRowBuilder object in a single variable, discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm building an embed with up to 2 actionrowbuilder depending on the length of an array. I'm aware that an actionrowbuilder can hold up to 5 buttons.

I'm getting an error saying **Invalid Body Form**.

If I place the actionrowbuilders directly to the components like this it works:

```
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [buttonRow1, buttonRow2]})
```

But I need it to only use the 2nd actionrowbuilder if the length of the array is greater than 5. I tried separating the 2 objects by comma, .join(","), but to no avail. Here's the code:

```
const array = ["button1", "button2", "button3", "button4", "button5", "button6", "button7", "button8", "button9", "button10"]

const buttonRow1 = new ActionRowBuilder();
const buttonRow2 = new ActionRowBuilder();

let buttons = [];
if (array.length < 5) {
    array.push(buttonRow1)
} else {
    array.push(buttonRow1, buttonRow2)
}

const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setDescription("This is a description.")
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [buttons.join()]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

const array = ["button1", "button2", "button3", "button4", "button5", "button6", "button7", "button8", "button9", "button10"];

// Calculate the number of rows needed
const rows = Math.ceil(array.length / 5);

// Create an array of MessageActionRow objects with buttons
const buttons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    const row = new MessageActionRow();
    for (let j = i * 5; j < (i + 1) * 5 && j < array.length; j++) {
        row.addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId(array[j])
                .setLabel(array[j])
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        );
    }
    buttons.push(row);
}

// Create the embed
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("This is a description.");

// Send the message with the components
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: buttons});
```

The `MessageActionRow` class is very similar to `ActionRowBuilder`, but it is specifically designed for use in the components array of the send method. You can create a `MessageActionRow` object with the new keyword, and then add components to it using the `addComponents` method.